# Are there any open source tools to view XML from a URL?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, notepad++

I have just downloaded Notepad++ and was looking to view XML from a URL. Does anyone know if it is possible to do this using Notepad++? If it is not, can you advise of any open-source apps which could do this? My Internet Explorer is really slow and begins to grind to a halt when dealing with a reasonable/large amount of XML.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use copy/paste to load the XML file:

- Copy the URL to the clipboard
- Press <kbd>Ctrl+o</kbd> to trigger the File=>Open menu
- Paste the URL into the input field and press <kbd>enter</kbd>